# HVGND v.s. GND for HV509

Tags: shift-register

When using a high voltage IC like the HV509, are there any design constraints with regard to the HVGND (pin27) and the logic GND (pin15).
By design constraints I mean any isolation from the main ground plane in any way.
My thoughts are that both grounds are at the same potential and should be the same, am I wrong? 
Any tips would be helpful.

Datasheet:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/hv509.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are connected inside the chip but routing of HiV return goes only to HVGnd and not Logic gnd to prevent ground shift noise of logic gnd, even though the load currents are small <1mA per port there may be reactive loads (pF).